# Can TCP implementation send several packets without waiting an ACK for the first one?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I basically know who TCP works from sockets point of view, but I can't figure out some thing.
Suppose I have now 1000 bytes to send, it comes for TCP-stack internal buffer and gets sent. These bytes are in this buffer until an ACK arrives. But If I will try to send 800 bytes more before the first ACK arrived, will a packet be sent? I guess the TCP window size is much more greater than 1800 bytes..

Comment: @DrMoishePippik What is the reason for you to comment about UDP while the question is about TCP?

Comment: so are you asking us about the windowing behavior when there is substantially less data than the window size for the last bits of buffered data? My guess is, if you were waiting for an ACK, you had previously exceeded the window size, and had 1000B let over and waiting on the acknowledgement so the next window could start, then adding data to the buffer before you start sending in the new window, you would still be waiting on the last window to be acknowledged, and the additional data would have no impact on behavior. can you help us understand why you might think it wouldn't?